# Why can I not setState with the value returned, is it out of scope?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The function appears to work, it is returning a new object, with the compiled data I need. I can't see why when i try to then set the state with the object, it is returning undefined.

The code explains this the best...if i need to edit the question or update the anything p[lease inform me and lets work through this together so we can achieve an answer.

Here are the data sets
    // locationPriceYear.json

```
{
    "YLP": [
        [
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "City of London",
                "price": "91449"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Barking & Dagenham",
                "price": "50460"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Barnet",
                "price": "93285"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Bexley",
                "price": "64958"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Brent",
                "price": "71307"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Bromley",
                "price": "81671"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Camden",
                "price": "120933"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Croydon",
                "price": "69158"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Ealing",
                "price": "79886"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Enfield",
                "price": "72515"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Greenwich",
                "price": "62300"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Hackney",
                "price": "61297"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Hammersmith & Fulham",
                "price": "124903"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Haringey",
                "price": "76288"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Harrow",
                "price": "84770"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Havering",
                "price": "68000"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Hillingdon",
                "price": "73835"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Hounslow",
                "price": "72232"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Islington",
                "price": "92516"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Kensington & Chelsea",
                "price": "182695"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Kingston upon Thames",
                "price": "80876"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Lambeth",
                "price": "67771"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Lewisham",
                "price": "60491"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Merton",
                "price": "82071"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Newham",
                "price": "53539"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Redbridge",
                "price": "72190"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Richmond upon Thames",
                "price": "109326"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Southwark",
                "price": "67885"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Sutton",
                "price": "71537"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Tower Hamlets",
                "price": "59865"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Waltham Forest",
                "price": "61319"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Wandsworth",
                "price": "88559"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-95",
                "location": "Westminster",
                "price": "133025,"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "City of London",
                "price": "108999"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Barking & Dagenham",
                "price": "50828"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Barnet",
                "price": "91111"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Bexley",
                "price": "63996"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Brent",
                "price": "72806"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Bromley",
                "price": "82210"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Camden",
                "price": "119560"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Croydon",
                "price": "68006"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Ealing",
                "price": "80214"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Enfield",
                "price": "71544"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Greenwich",
                "price": "62417"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Hackney",
                "price": "66327"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Hammersmith & Fulham",
                "price": "126914"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Haringey",
                "price": "81677"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Harrow",
                "price": "83216"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Havering",
                "price": "67347"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Hillingdon",
                "price": "72869"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Hounslow",
                "price": "73377"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Islington",
                "price": "89406"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Kensington & Chelsea",
                "price": "198312"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Kingston upon Thames",
                "price": "82561"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Lambeth",
                "price": "68780"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Lewisham",
                "price": "57838"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Merton",
                "price": "81277"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Newham",
                "price": "54376"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Redbridge",
                "price": "72861"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Richmond upon Thames",
                "price": "111174"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Southwark",
                "price": "65753"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Sutton",
                "price": "70031"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Tower Hamlets",
                "price": "67552"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Waltham Forest",
                "price": "62060"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Wandsworth",
                "price": "89092"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jan-96",
                "location": "Westminster",
                "price": "133843"
            },
        ]
    ]
}
```

etc... etc...

and there is then this for the post codes.

\ locationAndPostcode.json

```
{
    "City of London": "EC1A 7BE",
    "Barking & Dagenham and Havering": "RM9 4TP",
    "Barnet": "EN5 5RP",
    "Bexley and Greenwich": "DA16 3DN",
    "Brent": "HA9 9AA",
    "Bromley": "BR1 3NN",
    "Camden": "NW1 8QL",
    "Croydon": "CR2 7PA",
    "Ealing": "W13 0JX",
    "East Surrey": "GU8 5AD",
    "Enfield": "EN2 7AA",
    "Greenwich": "SE9 1DU",
    "Hackney and Newham": "E8 1FD",
    "Hammersmith & Fulham": "W6 8AB",
    "Haringey and Islington": "N8 9DJ",
    "Harrow": "HA3 5AG",
    "Havering": "RM12 6PL",
    "Hillingdon": "UB8 1JZ",
    "Hounslow": "TW3 2DL",
    "Islington": "N5 1RA",
    "Kensington & Chelsea": "W8 5SA",
    "Kingston upon Thames": "KT5 9NX",
    "Lambeth": "SW9 8HE",
    "Lewisham & Southwark": "SE6 4RE",
    "Merton": "SW20 9JT",
    "Newham": "E13 9AP",
    "Redbridge": "IG6 1NA",
    "Richmond upon Thames": "TW9 1EZ",
    "Southwark": "SE1 5AA",
    "Sutton": "SM1 1JA",
    "Tower Hamlets": "E14 7JE",
    "Waltham Forest": "E17 7LP",
    "Wandsworth": "SW12 8PB",
    "Westminster": "SW1H 0BB",
    "West Essex:": "IG11 8TU"
}
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class PostcodeConverter extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.sortData(this.setDataObj);
    }

    sortData = callback => {
        const mapped = locationPriceYear.YLP.map(i => Object.values(i));
        const result = mapped.map(i => {
            return i.map(j => {
                const location = j.location;
                const postcodeMatcher = Object.entries(locationAndPostcode).map(i => {
                    const local = i[0];
                    const post = i[1];
                    return [local, post];
                });
                postcodeMatcher.filter(element => {
                    if (element[0] === location) {
                        const obj = Object.assign({
                            location,
                            postcode: element[1],
                            price: j.price
                        });
                        console.log('obj', obj)
                        return obj;
                    }
                });

            });
        });
        console.log('result', result)
        callback(result);

    };

    setDataObj = obj => {
        this.setState({obj})
    }

    render() {
        console.log("this.state", this.state);

        return <div></div>;
    }
}

export default PostcodeConverter;
```

I expect this:

```
obj {location: "City of London", postcode: "EC1A 7BE", price: "91449"}

etc.. etc...
```

but I am seeing this:

```
(25) [Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33), Array(33)]
0: (33) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
1: (33) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
2: (33) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
3: (33) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
4: (33) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
5: (33) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
6: (33) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

etc... etc... (this is repeated for the length: 25)

::::=====UPDATE//UPDATE//UPDATE//UPDATE=====:::

This is the new code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import locationAndPostcode from "../../dummyData/locationAndPostcode.json";
import locationPriceYear from "../../dummyData/locationPriceYear.json";

class PostcodeConverter extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.sortData(this.setDataObj);
    }

    sortData = callback => {
        const mapped = locationPriceYear.YLP.map(i => Object.values(i));
        const result = mapped.map(i => {
            console.log(i);
            const mapLocalAndPost = i.map(j => {
                const location = j.location;

                const postcodeMatcher = Object.entries(locationAndPostcode).map(i => {
                    const local = i[0];
                    const post = i[1];
                    return [local, post, "steve"];
                });

        // for some reasn the above array is beying returned opposed to he 'obj' from down below. 
        // I don't see why or understand why this is happening. Need to test further why this is being returned here


                const matchAndCreateNewObj = postcodeMatcher.filter(element => {
                    if (element[0] === location) {
                        const obj = Object.assign({
                            location,
                            postcode: element[1],
                            price: j.price
                        });
                        console.log("obj", obj);
                        return obj;
                    }
                });
                console.log('matchAndCreateNewObj', matchAndCreateNewObj)
                return matchAndCreateNewObj

            });
            console.log('mapLocalAndPost', mapLocalAndPost)
            return mapLocalAndPost;
        });
        callback(result);
    };

    setDataObj = obj => {
        this.setState({ obj });
    };

    render() {
        console.log("this.state", this.state);
        return <div>{this.state && JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>;
    }
}

export default PostcodeConverter;
```

It is now returning `postcodeMatcher` instead of `obj` and I can't currently see why.

Comment: You are returning nothing to the `map` function. If you want to return result of `postcodeMatcher` add `return postcodeMatcher.filter()`.

Comment: @randomSoul I have adjusted the code and tried to fix the issue. I've isolated a new issue now and i'm unsure what to do. Please check the update.

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear what you want to have returned but I made some changes to your code. You get some empty arrays in my code because the locations names don't match always. For instance in locationPriceYear you have "Hackney" and this is called "Hackney and Newham" in the locationAndPostcode file. There are more of these "mistakes".

It now returns an array with a length of 2. These two arrays consists of objects that look like this `{ location: 'Wandsworth', postcode: 'SW12 8PB', price: '89092' }`

You can choose to map this array differently, if you want to.

```
sortData = callback => {
    const mapped = locationPriceYear.YLP.map(i => Object.values(i));
    const result = mapped.map(i => {
        return i.map(j => {
            const location = j.location;
            return Object.entries(locationAndPostcode).map(i => {
                const local = i[0];
                const post = i[1];
                return [local, post];
            })
            .filter(element => element[0] === location)
            .map(element => {
                return {
                    location,
                    postcode: element[1],
                    price: j.price
                };
            })  
        });
    })

    console.log('result', result[0], result[1])
    callback(result);

};
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Implementing this now. As for the "mistakes". It's data taken from a bad source and I've done my best to condense it into what I'm using, taking 40,000+ lines of JSOn down to about 1000.

As long as it gets me something usable at the end (doesn't have to be perfect) I'm pretty happy.

Comment: For some clarity I want to combine two sets of data based on the "location"  object property. That way, they have the price, location and postcode for the one location. It's data to be rendered on a map and it is patchy, but it's better that original CSV that was full of holes.

Thank you again, I'm not very good at structuring questions, especially when i'm stuck so thank you for the help.